# How can I improve this sql query

Tags: xml, sql-server-2012

I need to compare two xml columns. I currently have about 1000 rows of data that this is running against and it takes about 20min. Is there anyway I can improve this query to run faster.

```
SELECT
  MAX(T.CaseName) AS CaseName,
  T.PartNumber,
  T.NodeName,
  T.OldValue,
  T.NewValue
FROM (SELECT
  C.CaseName,
  old.N.value('../../../MaterialName[1]', 'nvarchar(100)') AS PartNumber,
  old.N.value('Name[1]', 'nvarchar(4000)') AS NodeName,
  old.N.value('Value[1]', 'nvarchar(4000)') AS OldValue,
  new.N.value('Value[1]', 'nvarchar(4000)') AS NewValue
FROM Cases c
CROSS APPLY BomDataCase.nodes('/TopBomComponents/TopBomComponents/TopBomComponent/BomMaterials/BomMaterial/BomMaterialAttributes/CustomBomMaterialAttributes/CustomBomMaterialAttribute') AS old (N)
CROSS APPLY BomDataChange.nodes('/TopBomComponents/TopBomComponents/TopBomComponent/BomMaterials/BomMaterial/BomMaterialAttributes/CustomBomMaterialAttributes/CustomBomMaterialAttribute') AS new (N)
INNER JOIN LibraryStatuses ls
  ON c.[Status] = ls.StatusId
  AND c.LibraryId = ls.LibraryId
WHERE old.N.value('../../../MaterialName[1]', 'nvarchar(100)') = new.N.value('../../../MaterialName[1]', 'nvarchar(100)')
AND old.n.value('Name[1]', 'nvarchar(100)') = new.n.value('Name[1]', 'nvarchar(100)')
AND old.n.value('Value[1]', 'nvarchar(100)') <> new.n.value('Value[1]', 'nvarchar(100)')
AND ls.name = 'Review') AS T
GROUP BY T.PartNumber,
         T.NodeName,
         T.OldValue,
         T.NewValue
```

Each xml string is fairly large about 1000 to 1500 lines.

This is the Cases table structure.

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Cases](
    [CaseId] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [LibraryId] [int] NOT NULL,
    [CaseName] [nvarchar](500) NULL,
    [ConfigId] [nvarchar](50) NOT NULL,
    [CurrentConfigId] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
    [PartNumber] [nvarchar](50) NOT NULL,
    [Image] [nvarchar](250) NULL,
    [Status] [int] NULL,
    [Price] [decimal](18, 0) NULL,
    [Comments] [nvarchar](500) NULL,
    [Error] [nvarchar](max) NULL,
    [LastRun] [datetime] NULL,
    [LastRunApplication] [nvarchar](100) NULL,
    [BomDataCase] [xml] NULL,
    [BomDataChange] [xml] NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_Cases] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [CaseId] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON, FILLFACTOR = 100) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY] TEXTIMAGE_ON [PRIMARY]

GO
```

Comment: Please tag this with your flavor of SQL.  I assume this is SQL-Server.

Comment: also try to provide sample table schema,indexes.If you can provide repro can be of much help

Comment: I'd post this to codereview. http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sql-server

Comment: I should have posted this here as well. i took @scslmon suggestion and posted this on codereview here. http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/141659/sql-query-to-compare-two-xml-columns They were able to get this down to 16 seconds. Very impressive.

Answer (score 1):

This answer comes late, hope it's still worth posting...

Reading XML should be done **straight forward only**. What is really heavy and expensive is *backward-navigation*, as you do this with `../../..`

It is better to go done to a certain level and continue with `APPLY` from this point.

Without having seen the actual XML this might be not correct, but you should get the idea:

```
SELECT
  MAX(T.CaseName) AS CaseName,
  T.PartNumber,
  T.NodeName,
  T.OldValue,
  T.NewValue
FROM (SELECT
  C.CaseName,
  old.mat.N.value('MaterialName[1]', 'nvarchar(100)') AS PartNumber,
  old.N.value('Name[1]', 'nvarchar(4000)') AS NodeName,
  old.N.value('Value[1]', 'nvarchar(4000)') AS OldValue,
  new.N.value('Value[1]', 'nvarchar(4000)') AS NewValue
FROM Cases c
CROSS APPLY BomDataCase.nodes('/TopBomComponents/TopBomComponents/TopBomComponent/BomMaterials/BomMaterial') AS old (mat)
CROSS APPLY old.mat.nodes('BomMaterialAttributes/CustomBomMaterialAttributes/CustomBomMaterialAttribute') AS old (N)
CROSS APPLY BomDataChange.nodes('/TopBomComponents/TopBomComponents/TopBomComponent/BomMaterials/BomMaterial') AS new (mat)
CROSS APPLY new.mat.nodes('BomMaterialAttributes/CustomBomMaterialAttributes/CustomBomMaterialAttribute') AS new (N)
INNER JOIN LibraryStatuses ls
  ON c.[Status] = ls.StatusId
  AND c.LibraryId = ls.LibraryId
WHERE mat.N.value('MaterialName[1]', 'nvarchar(100)') = mat.N.value('MaterialName[1]', 'nvarchar(100)')
AND old.n.value('Name[1]', 'nvarchar(100)') = new.n.value('Name[1]', 'nvarchar(100)')
AND old.n.value('Value[1]', 'nvarchar(100)') <> new.n.value('Value[1]', 'nvarchar(100)')
AND ls.name = 'Review') AS T
GROUP BY T.PartNumber,
         T.NodeName,
         T.OldValue,
         T.NewValue
```